# Framework7 Range Calendar Last Date scroll issue

Tags: html-framework-7

When range calendar has last day in current month with min date parameter set to yesterday as Today need in selection. After scroll & move to next month then calendar don’t go back to previous/current month.
Like Today is 31-05-2018 and it is available for selection on calendar initialization. But when move to June month then calendar cannot scroll back to May. Below is my code

```
calendarRange = botapp.calendar.create({
        inputEl: "#hdnDepDatesBus",
        containerEl: '#divDepDatesBus',
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate: yd, //yesterday date as today date need in selection
        rangePicker: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        value: [arrdDateBus],
        renderToolbar: function () {
            return '<div class="toolbar calendar-custom-toolbar no-shadow divCalanderMonth"><div class="toolbar-inner"><div class="left"></div><div class="center"></div><div class="right"></div></div></div>';
        },
        on: {
            init: function (c) {
                jq('.calendar-custom-toolbar .center').text(monthNames[c.currentMonth] + ' ' + c.currentYear);
            },
            monthYearChangeStart: function (c) {
                jq('.calendar-custom-toolbar .center').text(monthNames[c.currentMonth] + ' ' + c.currentYear);
            },
            change: function (c) {
                jq('.calendar-custom-toolbar .center').text(monthNames[c.value[0].getMonth()] + ' ' + c.value[0].getFullYear());
                if (c.value.length == 1) {
                    if (c.value[0].getMonth() > c.currentMonth) {
                        calendarRange.nextMonth();
                    } else if (c.value[0].getMonth() < c.currentMonth) {
                        calendarRange.prevMonth();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot search what i find solution is, what date you want to chose as min date chose 1 day before that date. Then use disabled date option to disable that date. this will solve scroll back issue and no extra past date will be enabled. 
This is solution and working. Also strange min date today is disabled for selection in framework7. Need to put 1 day before for min date for able to chose for today.

```
 calendarRangeTrain = botapp.calendar.create({
        inputEl: "#hdnDepDatesTrain",
        containerEl: '#divDepDatesTrain',
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        rangePicker: true,
        minDate: yd, // here yd is 2 days before today
        direction: 'vertical',
        value: [arrdDateTrain],
        disabled: [new Date(yd.getFullYear(), yd.getMonth(), yd.getDate() + 1)],
        renderToolbar: function () {
            return '<div class="toolbar calendar-custom-toolbar no-shadow divCalanderMonth"><div class="toolbar-inner"><div class="left"></div><div class="center"></div><div class="right"></div></div></div>';
        },
        on: {
            init: function (c) {
                jq('.calendar-custom-toolbar .center').text(monthNames[c.currentMonth] + ' ' + c.currentYear);
            },
            monthYearChangeStart: function (c) {
                jq('.calendar-custom-toolbar .center').text(monthNames[c.currentMonth] + ' ' + c.currentYear);
            },
            change: function (c) {
                jq('.calendar-custom-toolbar .center').text(monthNames[c.value[0].getMonth()] + ' ' + c.value[0].getFullYear());
                if (c.value.length == 1) {
                    if (c.value[0].getMonth() > c.currentMonth) {
                        calendarRange.nextMonth();
                    } else if (c.value[0].getMonth() < c.currentMonth) {
                        calendarRange.prevMonth();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```